# How to handle subroutine redefined errors in Perl

Tags: perl, warnings, subroutine

So I have a file that in short has this problem...

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
package Foo;

use strict;
use POSIX;

...

sub remove {
  ...
}
...
```

and I get a get an error saying the subroutine `remove` has been redefined. I know the problem, there is a subroutine called `remove` in POSIX. However, I don't know how to handle it. How is this problem typically solved?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

do this:

```
use POSIX ();
```

which will stop the export all default functionality of the POSIX module.  You will then need to prefix all POSIX methods with POSIX:: such as:

```
POSIX::remove(filename)
```

for the POSIX remove function.

Comment: Thanks. Is this conventional?

Comment: Yes, in general to avoid conflicting subroutine definitions its best to import nothing or only those subroutines you are sure will have unique names.

Comment: @floogads, it's more usual to say `use POSIX qw(mkfifo modf);` where you explicitly list all the functions you want to import.  That way, you don't have to use the `POSIX::` prefix all over, and you don't have to worry about conflicts with subroutine names in your program.

Comment: Does this work if `POSIX` was another script and not a Perl module ? Seems like it does not.

Answer (score 27):

The other way to suppress this warning is to put your subroutine redefinition inside a `no warnings 'redefine'` block:

```
{
    no warnings 'redefine';
    sub remove { ... }
}
```

Comment: I'd only do this if I was affirmatively replacing a subroutine definition because I was doing a little black magic to mask something, such as fixing a bug in a defined subroutine from a third party module). Otherwise, I'd first try to prevent that definition in the first place, as ether suggests.

Answer (score 21):

You can exclude certain symbols from being normally exported with the '!name' directive (see [perldoc Exporter](http://perldoc.perl.org/Exporter.html#Specialised-Import-Lists)), e.g.:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
package Foo;

use strict;
use POSIX '!remove';

...

sub remove {
  ...
}
...
```

Answer (score -1):

**Subroutine XYZ redefined at line N [perl error]**

You could wrap your routine in no warnings 'redefine' (which is lexically scoped):

```perl
no warnings 'redefine';

sub XYZ{
  ...
  ...
}
```

It worked for me!